# Change the default mount option on encryptfs home during login - pam_mount

Tags: pam, ecryptfs

I've Linux Mint 18.3 Sylvia and I've set up the encrypted home. It works fine out of the box. It is mounted with these default options:

`mount | grep /home`

`/dev/sda1 on /home type btrfs rw,noatime,ssd,space_cache,subvolid=505,subvol=/@home)`

`/home/.ecryptfs/franta/.Private on /home/franta type ecryptfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,`**relatime**`,ecryptfs_fnek_sig=156bddc12297b289,ecryptfs_sig=12e7815cddd2f77e,ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=16,ecryptfs_unlink_sig`

While using BTRFS and timeshift, it slows down my computer heavily when making snapshots. **I need to change mount option from relatime to noatime.** I can do it manually after the boot. But I am not able to figure out, how to force pam_mount to alter the mount options.

- I've tried to add the corresponding line to fstab without any effect. `/home/.ecryptfs/franta/.Private /home/franta            ecryptfs        noauto,user,rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime,ecryptfs_fnek_sig=156bddc12297b289,ecryptfs_sig=12e7815cddd2f77e,ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=16,ecryptfs_unlink_sigs     0       0`
- I don't know, where can I specify the ALIAS option as stated here: [mount.ecryptfs_private - eCryptfs private mount helper](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-mount/)
- I've tried approach suggested here: [ECryptfs - Sabayon](https://wiki.sabayon.org/index.php?title=ECryptfs), but without success